# How does the kendo UI schema model ID work?

Tags: kendo-ui

schema ID is really bothering me.

The logic I want is:

Open a modal popup window in grid A, and add the selected data (select row) in the modal popup as a new row in grid A.

Finally, we confirm this via the saveChanges () event.

This behavior works very nicely, but there are some things I don't understand.

```
schema: {
    data : 'list' ,
    model: {
        id: 'prodNo',
        fields: {
            orderDSeq: { editable: false },
            orderNo: { editable: false },
            prodNo: {type: 'string'},
            mtrlQt: {type: 'string'},
            prodSize: {type: 'string'},
            prodUnit: {type: 'string'},
            orderQnt: {type: 'string'},
            presentStkQnt: {type: 'string'},
            prodPrice: {type: 'string'},
            totalPrice: {type: 'string'},
            spplLimitDt: {type: 'string'},
            reMark: {type: 'string'}
```

Above is the schema of A grid, And

```
schema: {
    data: 'list',
    model: {
        id: 'key',
        fields: {
             prodNm: {type: 'string'},
             orderNo: {type : 'string'},
             prodNo: { type: 'string' },
             mtrlQt: { type: 'string' },
             prodSize: { type: 'string' },
             sStk: { type: 'string' },
             prodPrice: { type: 'string' }
```

Above is the modal popup schema.

It's a bit small, but it has a very similar structure.

The key question here.

This is not about A Grid, but about the schema ID of the modal popup.

Any changes made to Grid A did not affect this operation.

As far as I know, "Key(ID)" in the schema model should be one of the values ​​of the actual fields.

However, if you set this to one of the actual fields, the saveChanges () event will not detect grid changes. (ex, id:prodNm, id:prodNo... I did it because some of the information told me to exclude the Key data from the field, but the results were the same.)

However, if I specify the ID value as an arbitrary random character, this works very nicely.

Any word like "id:key, id:sound, id:stick .." This logic is performed for any characters that do not exist in the field.

Please make me understand this behavior.

How does model ID affect this logic?

ID is an important key for detecting changes, but I can't understand this groundless behavior.

Comment: It is used to determine Create versus Update. If that field is zero, it is treated as an update. Otherwise the record with that ID is updated. Has to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know that far. It is used to detect the change point and the key must be unique. But I have read that there is a "value that exists in a real field" as a more necessary condition.

However, if you do that, it will not work, and it will work only if you set the meaningless character to the ID (Key). why?